# how can i check the start of the string in php?

Tags: php, string, hyperlink

i want something like this

1. the user enter a website link
2. i need check the link if the link
   doesn't start with 'http://' I want
   to append 'http://' to the link .

how can I do that in PHP ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
if (stripos($url, 'http://') !== 0) {
   $url = 'http://' . $url;
}
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, but I can't stand it when people put the two operands of the comparison operators in that order.

Comment: I'm with Lucas on this. My reasoning is that it doesn't make sense if you read it as an english sentence. "if zero does not equal the outcome of this function..."

Comment: It's evidently less readable. But there is a rationale for it in C-derived languages where you can accidentally write ‘if (a=0)’. ‘if (0=a)’ will get caught quickly. Though personally I don't use this style, it is a matter of taste and coding standards.

Comment: It is personal taste. I always use this notation and I find it more readable.

Comment: In mathematics, you always put the variable on the left and the quantity on the right. As a habit formed from that, I always follow Lucas's order.

Comment: Just FYI this order is usually regarded as an anti-pattern - commonly referred to as "Yoda Conditional".

Answer (score 7):

I'll recommend a slight improvement over tom's

> ```
> if (0 !== stripos($url, 'http://') && 0 !== stripos($url, 'https://')) {
>    $url = 'http://' . $url;
> }
> ```

However, this will mess up links that use other protocols (ftp:// svn:// gopher:// etc)

Comment: yes, i thought of that after I saw your answer...

Answer (score 3):

```
if (!preg_match("/^http:\/{2}/",$url)){
    $url = 'http://' . $url;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would check for the some letters followed by a colon. According to the URI specifications a colon is used to separate the "schema" (http, ftp etc.) from the "schema specific part". This way if somebody enters (for example) mailto links these are handled correctly.

Comment: Yes this really should use a protocol regex (to allow for ports as well as both http and https).